# excel vba - how to increment a cell address?

Tags: excel, vba

the find function returns a range with address like $A$1

how do I increment it and use it to print the value of cell B1?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Offset(x, y)` to return the cell which is `x` units down and `y` units to the right.

For example

```
Range("A1").Offset(0, 1)   => Range("B1")
```

Also note there is `.Resize(x, y)` to take a single cell and make it table with `x` rows and `y` columns

```
Range("A1").Resize(10,3)   => Range("A1:C10")
```

Finally, use `.Cells(x, y)` to treat the cell as a table. So to read 10 rows starting from `A1` you do the following

```
For i = 1 to 10
    x = Range("A1").Cells(i,1).Value
    Debug.Print x
Next i
```